# How to split a file into two files based on a pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, split

In a file in `Linux` I have the following

```
123_test
234_test
abc_rest
cde_rest
and so on
```

Now I want to get two files in `Linux`. One which contains only records like below

```
123_test
234_test
```

and 2nd file like below

```
abc_rest
cde_rest
```

I want to split files based on what comes after `_` like `_test` or `_rest`

> Edited:

```
123_test
234_test
abc_rest
cde_rest
456_test
fgh_rest
```

How can I achieve that in Linux?

Can we use split function for this?

Comment: Can you please specify the criteria on which it shall be split? Lines starting with numbers vs letters? Or lines containing test vs rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single `awk` command for splitting:

```
awk '{ print > (/_test$/ ? "file1" : "file2") }' file
```

This `awk` command will copy all lines that start with digits to `file1` and remaining lines to `file2`.

Comment: Will this overwrite the file for each line? Because it is a single direction and executed for each line. In that case it should be replaced by >> and the file may be truncated in BEGIN{}

Comment: No inside `awk` even `>` behaves like `>>` so it won't rewrite for each line.

Comment: You are right. It is stated in gnu awk user's guide as: When this type of redirection is used, the output-file is erased before the first output is written to it. Subsequent writes to the same output-file do not erase output-file, but append to it. (This is different from how you use redirections in shell scripts.)

Comment: Why do you have `$0 ~` ?

Comment: @anubhava I want to split files that end with `_test` and `_rest` to two different files.  Your answer doesn't address this